# cocos2d. Object similar to ccsprite but without pictue?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, draw, ccsprite, cclayer

[CCSprite class reference](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_sprite.html)

I need an object in which I can draw and it also has fixed rect size with position. It seems `CCSprite` has everything I need but it can be initialized with picture only.

`CCLayer` can be initialized without picture but it hasn't rect. I have found content size only.

So what to do if I need an object similar to `CCSprite`, but I don't wan't to use pictures?

**EDITED**

I mean I need a Rect to detect touches. And `CCSprite` can be defined with a static method `spriteWithTexture:rect:`, where I can manually set its rect. But what to do if I don't want to set texture, but rect only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a sub class of `CCNode` and override its `draw` method.

You can look [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3adraw_update) for more detail

Comment: I have edited the question. Your answer is too partially answers this question.

Comment: Did you try setting the node's contentSize and position members ? This should be the rect you are looking for

Comment: Yes, I found these properties yesterday, but anyways it is size and position are accessed separately, so I need a category with a rect setter/getter. But finally if I will use these properties then is `CCNode` the most appropriate object? Or has it no difference?

Comment: This should work fine for you. CCNode is the basic drawing element. Any GUI object like CCSprite inherit from a CCNode for its specific functionality (i.e. loading texture etc..)